# What are some logic rules that are true for every kind of logic?

Tags: logic

What are some logic rules that are true for every kind of logic? Some rules from conventional logic are ignored like in paraconsistent logic, but I am wondering if there are logic rules that are true in every logic system that currently exists.

Comment: None. People explore logical systems where every classical rule is violated, although not all at once, see e.g. [logics without *modus ponens*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376048/152568).